# Magento Memcached enabled and working but admin grid filters being lost

Tags: magento, memcached

I have enabled memcache within my Magento install like so :

```
<cache>
    <prefix>mysiteprefix</prefix>
    <backend>memcached</backend>
    <memcached>
        <servers>
            <server>
                <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                <port><![CDATA[11212]]></port>
                <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
            </server>
        </servers>
    <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
    <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
    <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
    <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
    <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
  </memcached>
</cache>
```

As you can see I have 2 memcache instances running (ports 11212 & 11211).
The site is running well & a lot quicker since I enabled this however it seems that any filters I apply on a grid in the admin area are never remembered. 
If I revert back to saving the sessions in files it all works again.
Other than this everything appear to be working just fine. Any idea what might be causing this?

[edit]
Magento version is 1.4.1.1

Comment: Possibly memcache is losing the grid serialization: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/understanding-the-grid-serializer-block/

Comment: Thanks B00MER but I've now noticed that it seems to cause a couple of other issues also (one being "invalid form key" when searching in admin etc). Is there a way to specify file sessions for admin but memcache for frontend?

Comment: What version of Magento?

Comment: Magento version is 1.4.1.1. Thanks